# Combining a variable name with a number in javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have these 19 variables, "isTaken1-19" and I have everything set up to go through this function

```
function addtoList(localItemCode){  

        if(checkForDuplicate(localItemCode) == 1){
          document.getElementById('listItem' + (listTracker+1)).innerHTML = whatToSay;
          document.getElementById('amountItem' + (listTracker+1)).innerHTML = isTaken;
          listTracker += 1;
          addOne(localItemCode);
        }else if(checkForDuplicate(localItemCode) == 0){
            addOne(localItemCode);
        }
}
```

but on the "getElementById('amountItem' + (listTracker+1)).innerHTML = isTaken; instead of just isTaken I want it to be isTaken + localItemCode, in the sense that is knows if it's istaken1,isTaken2, isTaken5, etc. Like how ('listItem' + (listTracker+1)) is. IS this possible in javascript?

I apologize for my lack of terminology, I think what i'm trying to do is concatenate? I'll use an array if needed, I just wanted to see if this was possible.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] - you're not explaining what are your current values AFAICS

Comment: The best way for that is to use an **object** to wrap your variables and access the one you want by **key**.

Comment: as what i assume i understand you need to do a eval to the string ??

Comment: @AbdouTelb don't encourage him! `eval` is bad!

Comment: I think I've understood the question differently to other comments, but it sounds like you just want an array (or ye, an object possibly) so you can then use isTaken[localItemCode]

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir i think he can do this for demo purpose.

Comment: so Kraiden if I use isTaken[localItemCode], I would need to set up an object like. var isTaken = {1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0...etc or would that not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example to what I've said in the comment above:

```js
// The var wrapper varWrapper that wrap the vars in a wrapping object. So vars will be wrapped in varWrapper ...
var varWrapper = {};

// add variables like this
varWrapper["isTaken-1"] = 11.5;
varWrapper["isTaken-2"] = "this is number 2";
// ...
varWrapper["isTaken-101"] = true;

// the number of the variable you want
var num = 2;

// log it
console.log(varWrapper["isTaken-" + num]);
```

You can add all sort of variable names you want. Even this:

```
varWrapper["isTaken-genisis"] = "text";
```

Comment: this is perfect thank you, this will clean up my code a ton.